# Finding an intersection of two lines within a triangle by linear combination of vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors, triangles

In a general triangle, the point $D$ is defined such that $\vec{AD} = \frac{1}{3} \vec{AC}$, and $E$ such that $\vec{CE} = \frac{1}{4} \vec{CB}$. $F$ is the intersection of $\vec{AE}$ and $\vec{BD}$.

The task is to find $\vec{BF}$ as **linear combination of $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$**.

I'm aware that finding the $F$ would be straightforward by building a system of equations based on those two straights and solving them parameter-based.
However, that question specifically mentions linear combinations and is targeted at students who don't necessarly know about solving such equation systems yet.

Is there a way to solve this problem by using linear combinations and geometric rules **only**?

*Quick sketch of the problem:*

[image: sketch of problem]

Comment: Hint: choose $I$ on $AC$ so that $EI$ is parallel to $BD$.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks, but I don't see how I would approach this, neither how it would lead to a solution. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let $I$ on $CA$ so that $EI\parallel BD$, so $CI:CD=1:4$. Therefore we have

$$\vec{EI} = \frac14 \vec{BD}.\tag{1}$$

On the other hand, $CI:CD=1:4$ implies $CI = AC/6$, and so $AD:AI = 2:5$. Thus

$$ \vec{DF} = \frac25\vec{EI}.\tag2$$

From (1) and (2), 
$$\vec{DF} = \frac1{10}\vec{BD},$$
and so
$$\vec{BF} = \frac9{10}\vec{BD} = \frac{9}{10}(\vec{AD} - \vec{AB}).$$
Replace $\vec{AD} = \frac13\vec{AC}$ and we are done.

Comment: Now I understand it, thanks!